# How does "" (double quote symbol) have methods?

Tags: java, string, literals

How can a double quote (`""`) have a method even if you didn't actually declared it in a String. Like for example:

```
System.out.println("".length());
```

is `""` an object already without declaring it on a String?
or is it a keyword on Java that he knows it is already a string in the making?

Comment: well a `String` is an `Object` and `""` is a `String`.. so

Comment: This has to be a duplicate of an existing question but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JLS §3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) explains what string literals are ("A string literal consists of zero or more characters enclosed in double quotes.") and also says:

> A string literal is always of type String ([§4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.3)).

Answer (score 3):

The *empty string* is mentioned in the [JLS - **3.10.5. String Literals**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> The following are examples of string literals:
>
> ```
> ""                    // the empty string
> "\""                  // a string containing " alone
> "This is a string"    // a string containing 16 characters
> "This is a " +        // actually a string-valued constant expression,
>     "two-line string"    // formed from two string literals
> ```

It's a valid string, an empty one.

Answer (score 2):

`""` is an instance of `String`. You can call any `String` method on it. The fact it is literal doesn't change the fact that:

> A string literal is always of type String ([§4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)).

[--reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

The difference between literals and other `String`s is that literals are constructed at compile time and all equal literals have only one instance.

Comment: It is like an instance of a String or is it a literal String. its the same. Thanks sir.

Comment: Exactly. I have linked the specification. I strongly recommend reading the chapter about literals. Actually it's worth reading the whole documentation but it's tough.

Answer (score 1):

`""` is a `java.lang.String` literal. Like any other String object, you can call methods on it.

Answer (score 1):

It is called String literal, so you can use any of the `java.lang.String` methods.

> The String class represents character strings. All string literals in
>   Java programs, such as "abc", are implemented as instances of this
>   class.

Look at the  API from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), where you can find good explanation on strings and also on `java.lang.String` methods .

Answer (score 1):

Double qoute `""` is a string literal thats why it acts like an obj `String`.